# ANTLR to ignore "/" in oracle scripts

Tags: java, antlr

I am writing a parser in ANTLR to parse oracle scripts. I want to ignore "/" in the scripts.

> DROP PACKAGE package_name;/

Is there anyway to ignore this forward slash?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a lexer rule like the following to hide all slash characters in the input:

```
SLASH : '/' -> channel(HIDDEN);
```

Placing the token on the `HIDDEN` channel will hide the token from parser rules, but still show up in the text produced by calling `getText()` on you resulting parse tree. If you want to completely drop the character (even from `getText()`), then you can alter the rule as follows:

```
SLASH : '/' -> skip;
```

If you only want to ignore slash characters appearing at the end of a line, you could add a predicate like the following:

```
IGNORED_SLASH
  : '/' {_input.LA(1)=='\r' || _input.LA(1)=='\n' || _input.LA(1)==EOF}?
    -> channel(HIDDEN)
  ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at Alexander's PL/SQL parser on [github](https://github.com/porcelli/plsql-parser) or at mine [fork](https://github.com/ibre5041/plsql-parser), there you will find probably best open-source implementation of the PL/SQL parser.

But back to your question. You have two options you either implement a LOT of woodoo in predicates (as suggested by @280Z28) or can be seen [here:](http://sourceforge.net/p/tora/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/tora/extlibs/parsing.cpp/PLSQLGuiLexer.g#l1109)

Or you implement "island grammar". Since this really is an island grammar. PL/SQL files should be processed with three different lexers (one for SQL, 2nd for PL/SQL and 3rd for SQLPLUS statements). It might seem that predicates can solve it, but as you will have more and more sample data the code will get hardly mainteble. (For exmaple this slash should be ignored also if it's followed by white chars or if it follows some white chars).